# Replace a button with another on hover not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two buttons, and I want to display only one button to be displayed at a time but on hover, the button to be replaced by another and back to the first button on mouseout.

I came out with the following piece of code but on hover it keeps going back and forth between the two buttons, what would be the best way to do this ?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.price').on('mouseover',function() {          
              $(this).css('display','none');
              $(this).next('.buy').css('display','block');
          });

         $('.price').on('mouseout',function() {          
              $(this).css('display','block');
               $(this).next('.buy').css('display','none');
          });
        });
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-div" style="
    display: block;
">
                                                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default price" style="display: block; z-index: 9999999999999; position: absolute;"> $589.50                                                                         <!--  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default compare"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Compare</button> -->
                                    </button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default buy" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addToCart('43');" style="display: none; z-index: 999999; position: absolute;"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Cart</button>
                                </div>
```

$589.50                                                                         Compare -->
                                     Add To Cart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it keeps on showing/hiding all the time is because as soon as `.buy` is shown, the mouseout gets triggered, so put the mouseout on `.buy` element

```
$('.price').on('mouseover',function() {          
    $(this).css('display','none');
    $(this).next('.buy').css('display','block');
});

$('.buy').on('mouseout',function() {          
    $(this).prev('.price').css('display','block');
    $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m0ngsjkL/)